# Using Angular Material's Mat-Select Multiple - is there a way to move the selected option to the top of the list in the array after user chooses?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript, sorting

Is there a way to sort (move) items in an array so that the selected option goes to the top of the select menu - then sort the rest of the menu is in alphabetical order. When the user de-selects the options can it go back to the right spot in the alphabetical order?

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formGroup.value)" class="form">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
      <mat-select formControlName="toppings" multiple (selectionChange)="change($event)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>

  <button style="margin: 0 1rem 0 0;" (click)="clear($event)" mat-raised-button color="primary">Reset</button>
  <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" class="button" [disabled]="!formGroup.valid">Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  Validators
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select-list',
  templateUrl: './select-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select-list.component.scss']
})
export class SelectListComponent implements OnInit {
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  toppingList: string[] = [
    'Extra cheese',
    'Mushroom',
    'Onion',
    'Pepperoni',
    'Sausage',
    'Tomato'
  ];
  selectedToppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Tomato', 'Onion'];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.fb.group({
      toppings: new FormControl(this.selectedToppingList, Validators.required)
    });
  }

  change(e) {
    console.log(e.value);
    // sort toppingList array here with sort() function
  }

  clear(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.formGroup.reset();
  }

  onSubmit(post) {
    if (this.formGroup.valid) {
      console.log(post);
    }
  }
}
```

I've got a decent grip on how to use the sort() function in JS but to add items to the top of that list then sort the remaining is where I'm getting confused. Also when the user de-selects is where I get hung up a bit too. Any help would be great! Thank you!

Here is the StackBlitz I'm working with - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sort?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-list%2Fselect-list.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sort-xreuvi?file=src/app/select-list/select-list.component.ts

In the `constructor`:

```
selectedToppingList = ['Extra cheese', 'Tomato', 'Onion'];
toppingListMaster = [ ...this.toppingList ];
```

in `ngOnSubmit`:

```
this.change({value: this.selectedToppingList})
```

Your `change()` function

```
change(e:any) {
    console.log(e.value);
    let sel = [], unsel = []
    this.toppingList.forEach(item=> {
      if (e.value.indexOf(item) !== -1) sel.push(item);
      else unsel.push(item)
    })
    this.toppingList = [ ...sel, ...unsel ];
    // sort toppingList array here with sort() function
  }
```

and the reset

```
clear(e) {
    console.log(e);
    this.formGroup.reset();
    this.toppingList = this.toppingListMaster
  }
```

Comment: Thank you!!! This completely makes sense, I just need a bit of help to get there. I'll be able to figure out the rest so they are in alpha order. I really appreciate your help! Means a lot!